# How do I grab a specific sub-string of a file?

Tags: java, file, substring

I have a `txt` document called, `data.txt` with the following contents:

```
Account Name: Joe
  Account #: 50
  Account Balance: $105.0
  Check #: 110
```

I would like to parse the file above to grab the information proceeding the `:`. For example, if I were to grab `Account Name` I would like the method to return the String `Joe`.

I wrote a method, `get(String target)` as seen below, which isn't working properly.

*Please Note*: `target` is the field I would like to grab the inner-contents of. Using the example above with `Account Name`:

`getValue("Account Name")` (Returns) `"Joe"`

```
public static String getValue(String target)
{
    File file = new File("data.txt");

    try
    {
        reader = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String data = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (reader.hasNextLine())
    {
        sb.append(reader.nextLine()); 
    }

    data = sb.toString().replaceAll("\\s+", "").trim().toLowerCase();

    String value = null;

    if (data.contains(target))
    {
        //stuck here
    }

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Call this method for a required target
public static String getKey(String target) {
    Map<String, String> keyValueMap = loadKeyValueMap();
    return keyValueMap.get(target);
}

//load the keys and values only once from your input data file.
public static Map<String, String> loadKeyValueMap()
{
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    Scanner reader = null;
    try
    {
        reader = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    while (reader.hasNextLine())
    {
        String nextLine = reader.nextLine();
        String[] split = nextLine.split(":");
        if (split.length() >= 2) map.put(split[0].trim(), split[1].trim());
        else break;
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on the line `map.put(split[0].trim(), split[1].trim());` or more specifically: `split[1].trim()`.

Comment: the reason for this is your file might have some empty lines. Please check to remove the empty lines in the data.txt file. Or as an alternative you can do this before the line you are getting the error. if(split==null || split.length!=2) continue;

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        String text = reader.nextLine().trim();
        if (text.startsWith(target)) {
            String result = text.substring(target.length()+2);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

the rest after the while you can delete.

You just need to add a return statement at the end in case there is a no match.